# Raspberry PI 4 very slow predictions with TensorflowLite object detection api

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, raspberry-pi4

I'm running TensorFlow lite object detection in raspberry pi 4 model b 8GB of ram  and the prediction is very slow at 1.5 to 2 frame rate per second Is there a way to get better performance to improve prediction  at least 5 to 10 fps

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use this tool to try different running option: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark

Any maybe use --enable_op_profiling to see which ops make it slow. A quick fix might be enable multi-threading or use_gpu?

If you build TFLite use cmake, please set TFLITE_ENABLE_RUY=ON.